# Data Analysis on excel filtered table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have been trying to do Data Analysis on excel filtered table, but excel analyses data for the entire table. 
For example, I wish to analyze Bundesliga score analysis. I want to count the number of homegoals on a filtered table when Home team is Augsburg and for Season 2016/17. SO, how to use sum formula here (note that the row indices of filtered table do not sequentially increment by 1)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, are you attempting to sum the [Homegoals]column when filtered by [home] & [Season]?

If so, you just need to use the Subtotal function in excel.  See here:

http://www.microknowledge.com/try-this-it-works/subtotal-func-to-sum-filtered-data-excel/